# How to pass one of multiple middleware nodejs

Tags: node.js, middleware

I have a router like this

```
router.post("/roomplayers",[authjwt.verifyTokenAdmin,authjwt.finishedRoomManagement,authjwt.activeRoomManagement],
    RoomController.findPlayers)
```

and I would to get the controller `RoomController.findPlayers` if the admin have this `cofinishedRoomManagementde`permission
**OR** this `activeRoomManagement`
How can I do that

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to pass through many middleware's in your route the solution is below.

```
const tokenMiddleWare = (req, res, next) =>{
   
   //Your code here
   next();
}
```

```
const isAdminMiddleWare = (req, res, next)=>{
    
    //Your code here
    next();
}
```

**So now that we have two middlewares and one controller(I omitted it though) now you can work on route and pass those middlewares and controller but before I start I want point something important**

- So with the **next** you want to push the user down out of the middleware driving them closer to the route that they want to hit only when they meet all you validation that's when you want to push them down

```
router.post('/api/login', tokenMiddleWare, isAdminMiddleWare, (req, res)=>{
   
   authController.login(req, res);

})
```

Now this would be how you pass down multiple middlewares and using your controller